# Lotus notes 8.5 Inbox return to default sort and select next unread email

Tags: email, sorting, lotus-notes

My default Lotus Notes (v 8.5.2FP2) Inbox is sorted by date/time (newest at top). I can then do the following steps:

- select a message (single click to select)
- click the 'Who' header: the sort order changes to 'by sender' (e.g. to see their previous messages).
- I can select and open a previous message by the sender.

All ok so far. To return to the normal / default inbox view - i.e. sorted by date/time (newest at the top) I need to:

- click the 'Date' header (first time sorts in opposite order)
- click the 'Date' header again (this time sorts in correct order)
- click the 'Next Unread' navigation button to jump to the next newest message.

My issue is that I find it a bit of a pain to have to do these three clicks. Is there a simple 'Cancel sort' button? If not, what can I do to get back to the default inbox view and sort order, in one simple click?

I suspect that I will need to create a custom button that sorts the inbox and navigates me to the next message. There is a '@sort' function (which sorts a list) and a 'NavigateNextUnread' command, but I'm not sure how to perform the sort on the current inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel/undo the sort by sender and return to the default sort by clicking on the Who header again. This partially solves your problem as it returns the sort to the default sort order.

You can then use CTRL+HOME to move the cursor to the top - and use TAB to move to the next unread.

Answer (score 1):

To permanently sort a folder descending, i.e. with the most recent dates at the top:

1. Click the "context help" button (or hit F1).
2. Click the folder that keeps sorting the wrong way; right underneath the "show" box there is a "sort by" field. This is set to "sort by default". Change that to "sort by date" for each folder that isn't displaying the newest email at the top.

You have to do this for every folder, but once you do it will save your view. Every time you add a new folder, you need to go through the process again because it defaults to "sort by default."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I have my notes sorted by newest at top and everytime I closed notes it would switch the sort back to oldest at top.

I found this for my problem and decided I will deal with the sorting reset.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605679

> **Problem**
>
> When users sort the Inbox with newest mail on top and use the
> "Slide in a summary" notification option, the Inbox view can
> unexpectedly switch to newest mail on bottom.
>
> **Symptom**
>
> You notice that for some Notes 8.5.3 users, the sort order in the Inbox will change
> unexpectedly. Mail that should be sorted newest on top will suddenly
> flip to newest on bottom. Why does this occur?
>
> **Cause**
>
> This has been identified as a product defect under APAR LO66817. This will only
> impact users that use the "Slide in a summary" mail notification
> option (File -> Preferences -> Mail -> Sending and Receiving).
>
> **Resolving the problem**
>
> This problem is under investigation by Notes Product Development. To avoid having the sort order change, users can
> choose to disable the mail notification option by setting it to "No
> alert."

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes 8.5.3: The Date sorting always reverts back to latest email at the bottom.  Unlike previous Lotus Notes versions, the Date sorting is not maintained.

File / Preferences / User Preferences / Basics / Additional Options
Make sure the "Retain View column sorting" option is checked.

Reference:

[Retain View Column Sorting](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/5f27803bba85d8e285256bf10054620d/8613a48bbb4723ce85257a2c002ed47e?OpenDocument)